# File content and lock

Tags: c, linux, bsd

I found this code on the web which is able to lock a file and it works.

```
/*
** lockdemo.c -- shows off your system's file locking.  Rated R.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                     /* l_type   l_whence  l_start  l_len  l_pid   */
    struct flock fl = { F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET, 0,       0,     0 };
    int fd;

    fl.l_pid = getpid();

    if (argc > 1) 
        fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;

    if ((fd = open("lockdemo.c", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Press <RETURN> to try to get lock: ");
    getchar();
    printf("Trying to get lock...");

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("got lock\n");
    printf("Press <RETURN> to release lock: ");
    getchar();

    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;  /* set to unlock same region */

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Unlocked.\n");

    close(fd);
}
```

For my use case it's not enough.
While the file is locked, I am able to append data to lockdemo.c and I'd like to prevent that.
How can I do?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you run that program? Do you provide a command line argument to your program?

Comment: @Gerhardh no, without arguments

Comment: what does "and it works" mean exactly? If it doesn't prevent you from adding to the locked file, what does it prevent then?

Comment: @Gerhardh The _only_ visible effect is, if I understand the demo correctly, that a _second copy_ of the program, run while the first copy holds the lock, will block after printing "Trying to get lock..." until the lock is released by the first copy.

Comment: @zwol Exactly. Now, while the file is locked by lockdemo progam, if i run "echo hello >> lockdemo.c" from a shell then I am able to append these data and I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Unix file locking is strictly "advisory," meaning that it only interacts with itself.  Any process can open, read, write, truncate, etc. a locked file and as long as it doesn't call one of the locking functions it won't even notice that the lock exists.

This was an intentional design decision, made many years ago -- people can and do argue about whether it was the *right* design decision, but it's not going to be changed now.

If you tell us more about your larger problem, we might be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: technically speaking [there is a mandatory locking mode](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) but its buggy in linux and the linux kernel developers are moving towards removing it.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Yes, I know. It's my understanding that that only ever worked (sort of) for Samba's very specific use case, so I decided not to complicate the post with it. Also OP didn't say they were writing a Linux-specific program.

Comment: My program will write sensible data into a file and i'd want to prevent any accidental append to this file from whatever part. How could i do ? The program should work on Linux and Bsd

Comment: When the program exits, I can protect the file content making it immutable. For linux "chattr +i file", while for bsd, seems more appropriate "chflags schg file". Obviously, root can make whatever wants but, at least, I protect it by an accidental write. Is not there a method to protect it while i'm writing on it?

Comment: @stack12 Please don't use comments to explain your requirements. Your question is answered here. Changing the question might make the existing answer invalid. That's why I suggest to write a new question with a description of your requirements and a reference to this question. Specify what exactly you mean with "prevent any accidental append to this file *from whatever part*". How will you start your program? Does it run as a special user or as a special group?

Comment: @Bodo Ok. The root user will run the program and will handle it. The others user can only read and nothing else. The problem could born only if the root user inadvertently edit that file in some ways corrupting it.

Comment: @stack12 My questions were meant as hints what information you should provide in your new question. Don't answer here. Create a new question, and in this new question describe your use case and requirements and ask for advice.

Comment: @stack12 I concur with Bodo.  You should ask a new question with the specifics of your project.  You may find it useful to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and  https://xyproblem.info/ when thinking about how to phrase that question.

Comment: @stack12 Additionally: once you've read <https://xyproblem.info/>, contemplate this: If you posted a question saying "My program will write sensible data into a file and i'd want to prevent any accidental append to this file from whatever part. How could i do ?" I would tell you that _that question still suffers from the XY problem_ because "prevent accidental appends" is still a proposed solution to some problem -- you need to go back even further and explain _why you need an assurance that all the data in a particular file came from your daemon_.